# Alternative engine for Huggingface SpeechT5Processor processor?

Tags: text-to-speech, huggingface

Here is the code, I am wondering if there are better Huggingface processors/engines:

```
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
processor = SpeechT5Processor.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_tts")
model = SpeechT5ForTextToSpeech.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_tts").to(device)
vocoder = SpeechT5HifiGan.from_pretrained("microsoft/speecht5_hifigan").to(device)
embeddings_dataset = load_dataset("Matthijs/cmu-arctic-xvectors", split="validation")
```

I tried using the Transformers with the `microsoft/speecht5_tts text2speech` model but it has some voice glitches and only accepts maximum 600 tokens.

Any idea of an alternative?